# how to reverse an array in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL and have been practicing a bit on my own. Right now, I am reading on arrays in TCL and I am trying to reverse an array. The array TestArr is

```
Zero Orange
First Apple
Second Banana
```

So, basically I want to make it

```
Zero Banana
First Apple
Second Orange
```

But, I cannot find a way to find the index of the first element or the index of the last element because using
`foreach {index value} [array get TestArr]` will return the index values out of order.

The c++ code would be:

```
 for(int i=0;i>end;end--,i++)
 {
    int temp = TestArr[i];
    TestArr[i] = TestArr[j];
    TestArr[j] = temp;
 }
```

Is there any way to achieve this in TCL?

Comment: It seems that in TCL an Array is actually a Hash map or a dict, what you really want is a list.  As such they are unordered.

Comment: Is there some reason why you _want_ the array keys to be called `Zero`, `First`, and `Second`, or do you really want a list as OmnipotentEntity suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TCL an "array" is actually what's called a `hash map` in perl or a `std::map` in C++ or a `dict` in python.  As such they are unordered, so it doesn't make sense to reorder them.

What you actually want is called a `list` in TCL.  And the function to reverse your list is called `lreverse`.

[TCL List documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/list.htm)

[`lreverse` documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lreverse.htm)

From the comments below:

`lreverse` was added in 8.5. In 8.4, code it yourself with something like: `for {set i [llength $lst]} {[incr i -1] >= 0} {} {lappend reversed [lindex $lst $i]}` --[Donal Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301832/donal-fellows)

Comment: When I try to use lreverse, it says invalid command name "lreverse"

Comment: How are you attempting to use it?  Have you consulted the documentation?  What version of TCL?

Comment: I see the documentation is for TCL 8.5.11 . That could be the reason/

Comment: lreverse doesn't seem to exist in 8.4

Comment: This just means that you'll need to take an approach similar to the one in your question.  The important bit was the distinction between "array" and "list"

Comment: `lreverse` was added in 8.5. In 8.4, code it yourself with something like: `for {set i [llength $lst]} {[incr i -1] >= 0} {} {lappend reversed [lindex $lst $i]}`